# RxJS proper way of Creating Behavior Subjects from other Behavior Subjects?

Tags: angularjs, rxjs, observable

So I'm using an observable values in an angular application, and I want to make several behavior subjects derived from other behavior subject. I was transforming my behavior subjects with the .map() operator, but found out that I could not reference .value. I wanted to be able to reference the current value as was emitted last (so passed through the mapping function). A little digging around with the output of foo.map() I found I could get the functionality I wanted with:

```
let foo = /* some BehaviourSubject */
let bar = foo.map((x) => x / 2)
bar.operator.project(bar.destination.value) // to get the value as last emitted
```

But thats not very nice looking

Currently I'm doing something that looks like this to get the functionality i want:

```
foo = /* some observable*/
bar = foo.map((x) => x / 2).toBehaviorSubject()
foobar = bar.map((y) => y > 10).toBehaviorSubject()
```

toBehaviorSubject() is a function I've defined as the following

```
rx.Observable.prototype.toBehaviorSubject = function (initialValue) {
initialValue = initialValue || null
let subject$ = new rx.BehaviorSubject(initialValue)
this.subscribe((value) => { subject$.next(value) })
return subject$
}
```

I had earlier toyed with this as a solution, but opted for what I've shown above:

```
foo = /* some BehaviourSubject */
bar = new rx.BehaviorSubject( foo.value / 2))
foo.subscribe( (x) => {
   bar.next(x / 2)
})
foobar = new rx.BehaviorSubject(bar.value > 10)
bar.subscribe( (y) => {
   foobar.next(y > 10)
})
```

These work and all, but I have to ask, is there a standard convention for something that works like the above two examples?

**Edit-------------------**

Some added context might be helpful.

so I have a BehaviorSubject `auth.User$` that is sourced from a service I wrote for window.localstorage access which hands out BehaviorSubjects on its `localStorage.get(key)` function. I wrote this wrapper to deal with the fact that the localStorage change event fires on all tabs except the tab that changed the value.

Some parts of my application need to know whether the user has been initialized, or if the user is an anonymous user (some portlets can be accessed without logging in) or authenticated (for those which require the user to be logged in), and when these statuses change. In order to avoid duplicating the logic for producing the boolean values for isInitialized, isAnonymous, and isAuthenticated, I wanted to derive more BehaviorSubjects from `auth.User$`. I want them to be BehaviorSubjects specifically because some of the parts of the application only need the values on an on-call basis, and so being able to reference `auth.isAuthenticated$.value` is preferable to subscribing to that observable.

I used the `Observable.map()` function because I wanted to have observable values that fire when `auth.user$` does and which transform the emitted values from it, but would like it to still be a BehavorSubject as mentioned above.

So my question is essentially: is there a standard convention for applying a transformation/mapping function to a BehaviorSubject and still get a BehaviorSubject?

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve with this? Why do you want to push values into the second subject? Could you just combine two sources instead?

Comment: I'm using it to handle user authentication across tabs. the original observable is a behavior subject that's get it's next values from a `$window.localStorage` variable, and in the auth service I want to make behaviour subjects for initialized, anonymous and authenticated statuses for the user, to handle logging in and out and some portlets which can be viewed without needing to be logged in. these are then subscribed to in some cases and referenced with `auth.isAnonymous.value` (and the like) elsewhere.

Comment: Could you [edit] to add some context to the question? I think you might be trying to solve the wrong problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question, but basically a behaviour subject always has a value, so you can query the subject from that value at any point of time. I believe in Rxjs v5, `getValue` is the relevant method.

When you do `let foo = /* some BehaviourSubject */ let bar = foo.map((x) => x / 2)`, then `bar` is not a subject anymore, it is an observable, i.e. a producer of a stream of values. You need to subscribe to `bar` to start that producer and actually get a value. Your API seems to do just that. A shorter way is to do `bar.subscribe(anotherBehaviourSubject)`.

Now, do you really need to start the producer so early? i.e. do you actually need a behaviour subject in the first place? If you do, then of course go ahead.